# Empty SQL lite database after restart application

Tags: java, android, sqlite

After restart application my database always empty.

What I do wrong?

Did I clean database all the time?

**here is the Code for DB class..**

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;

    import java.sql.Date;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import galimski.igor.com.do_ing.Task;
    import galimski.igor.com.do_ing.TaskPriority;


    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final String TAG = "SQLite";

        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TaskDatabase";

        private static final String TABLE_TASK = "Task";

        private static final String COLUMN_TASK_ID ="Id";
        private static final String COLUMN_TASK_SHORT ="ShortDescription";
        private static final String COLUMN_TASK_FULL = "FullDescription";

        private static final String COLUMN_TASK_CREATIONDATE = "CreatedDate";
        private static final String COLUMN_TASK_COMPLETIONDATE = "CompletionDate";

        private static final String COLUMN_TASK_PRIORITY = "Priority";

        private static final String COLUMN_TASK_SHOWN= "Shown";

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context)  {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.i(TAG, "MyDatabaseHelper.onCreate ... ");

            //        String script = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NOTE + "("
            //                + COLUMN_NOTE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_NOTE_TITLE + " TEXT,"
            //                + COLUMN_NOTE_CONTENT + " TEXT" + ")";
            //String script = "CREATE TABLE `Task` ( `Id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `ShortDescription` TEXT NOT NULL, `FullDescription` TEXT, `CreatedDate` TEXT NOT NULL, `CompletionDate` TEXT NOT NULL, `Priority` TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`Id`) )";

            String script = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TASK + "("
                            + COLUMN_TASK_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                            + COLUMN_TASK_SHORT + " TEXT,"
                            + COLUMN_TASK_CREATIONDATE + " TEXT,"
                            + COLUMN_TASK_COMPLETIONDATE + " TEXT,"
                            + COLUMN_TASK_PRIORITY + " TEXT,"
                            + COLUMN_TASK_SHOWN + " TEXT" + ")";

            db.execSQL(script);
        }


        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.i(TAG, "MyDatabaseHelper.onUpgrade ... ");

            if (oldVersion != newVersion) {
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TASK);
                onCreate(db);
            }

        }

        // Called when the database connection is being configured.
        // Configure database settings for things like foreign key support, write-ahead logging, etc.
        @Override
        public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onConfigure(db);
            db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
        }

        public void AddTask(Task task) {
            Log.i(TAG, "MyDatabaseHelper.addTask ... ");

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put(COLUMN_TASK_SHORT, task.GetShortDescription());
            values.put(COLUMN_TASK_FULL, task.GetFullDescription());

            values.put(COLUMN_TASK_CREATIONDATE, task.GetCreatedDate().toString());
            values.put(COLUMN_TASK_COMPLETIONDATE, task.GetCompletionDate().toString());

            values.put(COLUMN_TASK_PRIORITY, task.GetCompletionDate().toString());

            db.insert(TABLE_TASK, null, values);

            db.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have edited your question.. now just delete the answer where you pasted your question code.

Answer (score 0):

Please test your application on the real android device and check if the same problem persist and just restart the application don't re-run from android studio because android studio will re-install the application every time you re-run it resulting in the empty database.

1)Run the application on the device
2)Add the data into the database 
3)Close the application
4)Remove it from recent apps.
5)Re-Run it from the menu not from the android studio.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is not that the database is being deleted or emptied; it's because the insert will not insert any data as you are trying to insert using column **FullDescription** (as per `values.put(COLUMN_TASK_FULL, task.GetFullDescription());`). **However, that column does not exist in the table** (according to the create table SQL you have shown).

You either need to comment out or delete the line `values.put(COLUMN_TASK_FULL, task.GetFullDescription());`

or if you need the column then change

```
String script = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TASK + "("
                                + COLUMN_TASK_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                                + COLUMN_TASK_SHORT + " TEXT,"
                                + COLUMN_TASK_CREATIONDATE + " TEXT,"
                                + COLUMN_TASK_COMPLETIONDATE + " TEXT,"
                                + COLUMN_TASK_PRIORITY + " TEXT,"
                                + COLUMN_TASK_SHOWN + " TEXT" + ")";
```

to

```
String script = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TASK + "("
                            + COLUMN_TASK_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                            + COLUMN_TASK_SHORT + " TEXT,"
                            + COLUMN_TASK_FULL + " TEXT," 
                            + COLUMN_TASK_CREATIONDATE + " TEXT,"
                            + COLUMN_TASK_COMPLETIONDATE + " TEXT,"
                            + COLUMN_TASK_PRIORITY + " TEXT,"
                            + COLUMN_TASK_SHOWN + " TEXT" + ")";
```

If you change the table's definition by adding the column you will need to rerun the App but only after doing **one** of the following:-

1. Delete the App's data
2. Uninstall the App
3. Change `private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;` to `private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;`

*This is because the **onCreate** method **only runs once when the database is created** **1** and **2 delete the database**, **3** invokes the **onCreate** method via the **onUpgrade** method*